# How to create launcher as windows service using jpackage (Java 19)

Tags: java, windows, service, jpackage, service-installer

I want to create an installer with `jpackage` that registers my java application launcher as a Windows service.

I have installed WiX Toolset v3.11.2.

I have tried to create my installer by specifying the [--launcher-as-service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html#option-launcher-as-service) flag which is supported in Java 19 [JDK-8275062](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8275062) but I am getting the following error:

```bash
> jpackage --type msi -i . --main-jar my-app.jar --name my-app --app-version "1.0.00" --dest . --win-shortcut --win-menu --launcher-as-service
Bundler MSI Installer Package failed because of java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jdk.jpackage.internal.InstallableFile.srcPath()" because "this.serviceInstaller" is null
```

The documentation mentions a certain [service installer executable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html#resource-directory-files-considered-only-when-building-windows-msiexe-installer) (`service-installer.exe`) as a resource to consider. Any idea where I can find this executable and what would be the best thing to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to manage this issue by configuring the `--resource-dir` option to specify the NSSM resource path, and I have renamed `nssm.exe` to `service-installer.exe`.

```bash
> jpackage --type msi -i . --main-jar my-app.jar --name my-app --app-version "1.0.00" --dest . --win-shortcut --win-menu --resource-dir "C:\Program Files\nssm-2.24\win64" --launcher-as-service
```

Comment: Yes, `jpackage` has been designed to work with NSSM: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.jpackage/windows/classes/jdk/jpackage/internal/resources/service-config.wxi#L6 . If you want to use another service wrapper such as WinSW, you will need to override `service-config.wxi` and `service-install.wxi`

Comment: please give me more details about this answer because the installer refers to `service_installer.exe` as a service, not my application `exe`