# Can't Create windows service using JPackage

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, jpackage

everyone
I have problem with `jpackage` when i attemp create `windows service`
after i create java application and need create `installer` using `JPackage`
by using the following commnad

`jpackage --type msi --input . --app-version 1.0.00 --name my-application  --main-jar ./my-application.jar --main-class org.example.Main --icon "icon.ico"  --win-dir-chooser --win-shortcut --win-menu  --jlink-options --bind-services`

my `installer` work fine, but my problem i need application run as a `windows service` and `Jpackage` using [nssm](https://nssm.cc/download) to help create `installer` using `Jpackage` as a `windows service` but there problem after run the following command

`jpackage --type msi --input . --app-version 1.0.00 --name my-application  --main-jar ./my-application.jar --main-class org.example.Main --icon "icon.ico"  --win-dir-chooser --win-shortcut --win-menu --resource-dir "C:\nssm-2.24\win64"  --launcher-as-service --jlink-options --bind-services`

`installer` run `nssm.exe` not my application in windows service layer

can anyone help me in this problem?

I attemp to read [JPackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A) documentation

and using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951976/how-to-create-launcher-as-windows-service-using-jpackage-java-19) as reference to create `installer` using `Jpackage` and `nssm`