# How to convert java application with process in background to installer?

Tags: java, deployment, background-process

I am working on a screen time monitoring app in java.

[image: Here are my classes]

- 'MainStart' class is a background process that tracks usage time.
- 'Stage1' class is a GUI app for reading data and showing it in charts.

I want to pack this project into installer and let users download it from website. The 'MainStart' class must be run together with computer and work in background constantly. For the 'Stage1' class I would like to create a desktop shortcut. How can I do that?

After the installation, I want the program to work exactly the same as it works when I run the 'MainStart' class and then 'Stage1' class to see data. (User uses only the 'Stage1' class. The rest is automatic).

I've tried playing with NSIS but I have no idea how to create the .nsi scripts. It seems to require a few weeks of learning. I just want to quickly deploy my app with no extra weeks spent on learning NSIS scripts. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `MainStart` should probably run as a service. You will need a service wrapper such as the Tanukisoft one. I can't recommend one but googling should come up with something

Comment: Have a look at `jpackage` with `--launcher-as-service` option and read [How to create launcher as windows service using jpackage (Java 19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951976/how-to-create-launcher-as-windows-service-using-jpackage-java-19)